# Error connecting to MySQL server in Docker container

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server running in a Docker file
Iam getting  error

Here's the relevant section of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN apt-get update && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

# Clone the phpdemo repo from Github
RUN git clone https://github.com/<<myrepo>> /var/www/html/
FROM mysql:latest
USER root
RUN chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD my_password

CMD service mysql start

# Create a new database using the root user
RUN mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE mydb;"
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
#0 0.286 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```